# Installing Plugin to Eclipse Doesn't Work

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to install JAWC (as a local file) to Eclipse, but it doesn't seem to work. I've clicked through Help-->Install New Software, then clicked add, then clicked archive, and then browsed to jawc-1.0.1.zip. However, it informs me that "No software site found at jar:file:/Users/me/Desktop/jawc-1.0.1.zip/. Do you wish to edit the location?"

Any ideas?

By the way, here is the link to jawc: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jawc-wallpaperc/files/

EDIT:
I'm sorry, I should've mentioned my problem. I'm attempted to use jawc to programmatically set my desktop wallpaper. However, I'm unsure about how to integrate jawc with eclipse

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you are trying to accomplish. The above question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jawc does not seem to be a plugin for eclipse.

> Jawc stands for Just Another Wallpaper Changer or, if you prefer, JAva
>   Wallpaper Changer.  It is a Plugin-Based Wallpaper Changer and can
>   change your desktop background picture from a lot of different sources
>   like your PC's folders, or Flickr, or VladStudio, just depending on
>   which plugins you enable.

See http://jawc-wallpaperc.sourceforge.net/